# web service not getting values when debug but consuming via WCF test client it works

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, wcftestclient

I am consuming a web service through the debug mode in VS2013 in my project, if 14 records are there but not coming,

But  when consuming via WCF Test Client, records are coming ,

please anybody can suggest me  what would be the case in here ?, 
configurations and service url are same,

web configuration

```
<endpoint address="http:/localhost:8080/SCP/Apis/Admin/Services/UserService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" contract= "AdminUserService.IUserService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserService" />
```

and I  call to service client like this.

```
var dto = new UserServiceClient().GetActiveUsers().ToList();
```

Comment: Any code? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @Joze
I get active user s from service and already add service reference to my project
var dto = new UserServiceClient().GetActiveUsers().ToList();

Comment: Please add any edits to the question itself and format it accordingly.

Comment: I got the fact of the issue. I have to update the service reference. once I updated the service reference, it's ok. I wondered why I didn't get an error.
Anyway thanks @joze.